# Partition Over Ordering Effect

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Does the Oracle clause `OVER(PARTITION BY SUM(some_field))`
have an implicit ordering effect and will my result data be sorted by `SUM(some_field)` without an additional
`ORDER BY  SUM(some_field)` clause?

Comment: The only, (really the ***only***) way to guarantee any defined order of the result is to use `order by`. Any "order" you see without an `order by` is purely a coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  An analytic function in the `SELECT` statement does not imply any particular ordering of the result.  Remember that you can have mulitple analytic functions in your query each of which is looking at rows in a different order so it wouldn't make sense for there to be an implied ordering of the result.  If you want your results returned in a specific order, use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks! And what if I have a particular case? I mean ONLY ONE analytic function in SELECT statement, i.e. `SELECT MIN(SALE_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY SUM(SALE_SUM)) FROM sales_1 GROUP BY sale_date` . Can I be sure for odering results by `SUM*SALE_SUM)`?

Comment: @Andrew - My answer stands-- there is no implied ordering.  If you care about the order that results are returned, you must always include an `ORDER BY`.  Of course, it is possible that including an analytic function influences the optimizer to pick a query plan that happens to return results in a particular order.  But that shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: OK, but so does an `ORDER BY` clause inside `OVER()` expression, right? Because I see a `WINDOW SORT` in 'explain plan' as a last operation, I can conclude that I haven't have to add a final ORDER BY clause. Am I right?

Comment: @Andrew - If you want the order of results to be guaranteed, you must add an `ORDER BY` clause.  Always.  Every time.  No exceptions.  It is possible that you might get the results in the order you want without specifying an `ORDER BY` but that is likely to change over time as the query plan changes, as new versions of Oracle come along, and as the underlying data changes.  Unless you want someone asking why results aren't ordered in 6 months because a query plan changed, include the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Years ago people used to be the same about `GROUP BY` - why add an `ORDER BY` when the results always come out in order anyway?  But they don't now (generally) due to optimiser changes.

Comment: Tony, I know that `GROUP BY` without `ORDER BY` is doubtful when we speak about sorting. I just want to ask: Is `ORDER BY` inside an `OVER()` is self-sufficient for that?

Comment: @Andrew - No, it is not.  Only an `ORDER BY` clause in the query guarantees the order of results.  Anything else is subject to change in the future when you stop getting lucky.

Comment: OK, thanks to ALL! Sorry, how can I close a question? I'm a newbie here :-)